# One ASP.net WebAPI Application, Multiple Signal-R Backplanes (Sql Server databases)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Is it possible to create multiple backplanes within Signal-R?

We're working on an ASP.net WebAPI Sass application and are looking to implement Signal-R for "real-time" web functionality. Since we'll be hosting the application a web farm, client-connection state will be managed through a SQL Server backplane.

The application is multi-tenant - but database is not. The application determines which connection string to use and all client requests talk to their appropriate database. Now the code for configuring the Signal-R SQL Server backplane within Application_Start() is:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to create multiple backplanes with Signal-R, basically loop through each connection string and call the above code?

Thanks for checking this out!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to eliminate the single point of failure, I suggest setting up a failover server in case the primary SQL Server machine goes down. Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231721.aspx

If you simply need more performance than a single SQL Server instance can provide, I suggest using Redis as the backplane.

In either case, I doubt attempting to use "multiple backplanes" will be helpful, unless you intend to map certain hubs to certain backplanes for load distribution.